# Gmail Style Tabs in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

brand new to angular and I was just hoping for a little guidance on something that I could achieve relatively quickly in jQuery.

As a pet project I'm coming up with a comic organiser web app to learn angular. I started the project in jQuery looking like so...

```
<div id='main'>
    <div id='library'>

    </div>
    <div id='series' data-currently-loaded-series='1234'>

    </div>
    <div id='comic' data-currently-loaded-comic='4321'>

    </div>
</div>
```

Now I based this design off of how gmail works it, it doesn't destroy tabs it simply hides them, or caches them, so that you'll never have load the same piece of information twice.

Clicking on a series in library loads it into the series div. If the 'currently loaded series id' matches the one I'm trying to load it won't load anything as it sees that it's already loaded it, so on and so forth...

I felt this sort of design would be invaluable for my little project as a lot of the comic cover images are high res and navigating between views would be a bit pointless, I of course know that images are usually cache by the browser, but I still couldn't see a reason to destroy the divs when I could simply hide them. I guess I'm trying to minimise data requests.

I've seen a few examples of this tab like behaviour around the internet but gmail is like the only instance I could find where they didn't destroy previous views/tabs on navigation.

Enter Angular...

I've found that when switching between partials and views it destroys the old data and I'm not too sure if this behaviour can be disabled. I thought I could set up the same div layout I had before and just load in multiple views and switch but Angular doesn't play well with multiple views (apparently UI-Router might be solution here). Even doing this all in one view wouldn't be ideal as I'm not too sure I'd be able to use URL routing...

I guess what my ultimate question is does anyone know the name of this tab caching mechanism gmail employs? If not could anyone point me in the direction of how I'd go about creating something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Bootstap and Ui bootstrap for angular.
A simply tutorial: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/08/14/dynamic-tabs-with-angularjs-and-ui-bootstrap.aspx